# Get values of elements at specific indices in a matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I was wondering if there is a quick way in matlab (pretty sure there is and I just don't know it!) to get all the values of an array at specific indices. Example: If I have an array:

```
a = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

and I have my list of indices `[2,3]`, I am looking for a function that will give me back `[3,5]`
which are the values at indices 2,3 in the array 'a'. The straightforward solution is to loop through and index one at a time but I would like to know of a faster more efficient built-in function if one exists.

And as far as I have read, find function only returns the index where a particular value is present. I am looking for the opposite scenario wherein I pass in the indices as a array and all the values present in 'a' at those indices are returned. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) is basic MATLAB.  Hard to do anything without  it...

Answer (score 3):

Found it! It's as simple as doing `a([2,3])` and the required values are returned!

Comment: On a related note, read [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). It will be useful if you have `[row,col]` indices stored in a 2-column matrix, and if you want to extract those elements from your matrix, without the `for` loop. This is the command you will have to use.

Comment: No need for double parentheses: `a([2,3])` works too.